# Matching in a bipartite graph that saturates all vertices

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Let $G=(S,T;E)$ be a bipartite graph without isolated vertices.

For every edge $e\in E$,   e $=$ $st$ $($ s $\in S$, $ t\in T$) happens the inequality $dG(s)$ $>=$ $dG(t)$.

Prove that in $G$ exists a matching which saturates all the vertices of S.

My thoughts:

I found that there exists $Theorem$ $Hall(1935)$ which says:

Let $G$ $=$ $(S,T;E)$ be a bipartite graph. There exists a matching in $G$ which satures all the vertices in $S$ if only and only

$|NG(A)|$ $>=$ $|A$|,  $∀A ⊆ S$. (NG represents the neighbors i suppose)

But I don't know how to apply this theorem to my problem, or if anyone has other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The saturation part actually just says there is a matching $E_M$ with $$\forall_{s \in S} \exists_{t \in T} [e(s,t) \in E_M]$$

Then use [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem) in its Graph theoretic formulation.

It suggests to use contradiction by finding a matching $E_M$ that has $s \in S$ and no $t_M \in T$ in the matching. By the properties you should try to prove that a better matching $E'_M$ exists, that does include $s$.

The alternating paths strategy might work, or you may need to modify it a bit using your inequality.

Comment: I read about alternating path but I don't think this is a solution for my problem, it would help if i need maximum cardinality matching(or i misuderstood it).

Comment: I tried proof by contradiction with the idea of start you gave but i get stuck at finding E′M, could you help me with some more details?

Comment: Then maybe use induction instead. A first element in $S$ is easily saturated. For each following element of $S$, a matching can be found via the alternating path method.

Comment: Or you should prove that $dG(s) \ge dG(t)$ implies $∀A ⊆ S |NG(A)| \gt |A|$

Comment: I found an idea of demonstration by induction for matching in a bipartite graph, and it solves my problem(it uses Hall theorem too). But I still don't understand why the exercise gives that inequality $dG(s) >= dG(t)$ . I could write that demonstration, but i'm missing that relation.

Comment: If you have 1 element is T that is connected to two elements in S would be a counterexample